# C++ reading file created in ProgramData with "run as Admin"

Tags: c++, activex, virtualization, uac, readfile

I have ActiveX that deploys my application on host. The files are placed in ProgramData so for deployment on Win7 UAC enabled the browser started with "run as Administrator".
As part of deployment it creates some log file.

Late,on some machines, when the same ActiveX tries to read the log file (this time IE is executed without elevation but the user is admin) - the file contains only the first line.
I don't get any "Access denied" and so on. If I start IE as admin - I'm getting the full information from the file.

Please note - that initial write file and later read file happens under the same user that is admin.

I understand that UAC visualization happens - but the issue is reproduced only on some machines.
So it is may be it is related to specific setting in UAC ? 
Please help

Zaky

Comment: Well, mostly logging. I'm sure that ifstream method of the reader receives correct path to ProgramData folder. And actually I'm in research how to continue from here. In some article I read about - Application Compatibility Toolkit so I was thinking to go that way...

Comment: Are all machines running x86 version of windows or x64 version? 
Do they have the same service packs ? Are all conditions exactly the same? the IE version? Did you try with another language like C# to see if thats a language trick or just some configuration issue causing the problem ? What exactly are you logging ?